# Windows 7 occasionally crashes with bugcheck code 0x124

Tags: windows-7, bsod, machine-check-exception

I installed Windows 7 Ultimate Edition 32-bit on my Acer Aspire 4520 notebook. Whenever I am installing software, surfing the internet or watching a video online, the system occasionally crashes with bugcheck code 0x124.

Since the original memory stick had some hardware errors (tested using Memtest86+), I replaced it with a 2GB Kingston memory stick. However the problem still remains after the replacement.

Can someone figure the problem out for me?

Here is my bugcheck dump:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                              
*
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124) A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon. Arguments: Arg1: 00000000, Machine Check Exception Arg2: 8d65977c, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure. Arg3: 00000000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value. Arg4: 00000000, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

Debugging Details:
------------------


BUGCHECK_STR:  0x124_AuthenticAMD

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

STACK_TEXT:  


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: hardware

IMAGE_NAME:  hardware

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x124_AuthenticAMD_PROCESSOR__UNKNOWN_PRV

BUCKET_ID:  0x124_AuthenticAMD_PROCESSOR__UNKNOWN_PRV

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: Its an uncorrectable hardware fault, start by updating all your hardware drivers...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557321(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try `!analyze -v` for more information, as I feel some information misses.

Other than that, [the error is what it says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557321%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). You need to start troubleshooting hardware...