# Finding cause of bugcheck 0x124 - WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR

Tags: windows-7, bsod, hardware-failure, hp-elitebook

This is somewhat related to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/273630)

For some time now, my system sporadically

1. hangs with the sound card playing the previous sample in a loop and sometimes a flickering screen.
2. bluescreens with above error code.

This is an HP Elitebook 8740w and I have turned to the HP support for help and to a local HP partner afterward, both in vain.

I'm a driver developer as fellow devs will likely guess by my nickname and I am able to analyze memory dumps (beyond `!analyze -v` ...). However, since this is inevitably a hardware issue, I never get a full (uncorrupted) memory dump that gives me more than the bugcheck code itself (`WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR`) and the fact that parameter 1 is `0x4`, making this "An uncorrectable PCI Express error occurred."

The problem is that as of yet I have to get a memory dump with intact contents of the memory to which parameter 2 supposedly points (`WHEA_ERROR_RECORD`). Short of any other solution I have now resorted to attaching a debugger via Firewire to the system so I can hope to inspect the memory upon crash.

I have upgraded all drivers to their latest available version, but my suspicion is that this is not a software problem at all. In all cases I watched some kind of video stream, though sometimes they were from hard drive and sometimes from a live stream. HP told me that multiple components on the motherboard are connected via PCI Express and after the local HP partner claimed they couldn't reproduce it (after all it happens sporadically to me as well) and returned it without doing anything.

I need some way of at least tracking down the (hardware) component that causes the fault or better yet a way to trigger the fault myself to demonstrate to them.

Note: it does not appear to have to do with the temperature of the system ("overheating") as most of the time the system was chilling and not under heavy load.

Comment: @Moab: did you read my question? I am not getting any intact dump files, so I cannot do a post-mortem debug. I need alternatives, which is the reason I asked in the first place. I'm doing several (kernel mode) post-mortem debugging sessions every year in my job, so I do know how to do it ...

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: I'd like to add that HP did not manage to rectify the issue. Therefore at the end of 2012 I received a replacement (8770w) for my old one. They replaced the CPU and the graphics card in different repair sessions without any improvement. Attempts to debug via Firewire all failed, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), did you try any of the suggestions? Viruses and unreadable sectors are first on my suggested possibilities list.

> 1. Download and install updates and device drivers for your computer from Windows Update.
> 2. Scan your computer for computer viruses.
> 3. Check your hard disk for errors.

Scan the drive offline [using a boot AV cd.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/what-is-windows-defender-offline) remove anything it finds. [More on viruses and malware removal.](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now/157533#157533)

[Run a chkdsk /r on the hard drive](http://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=6565).

Comment: yes I did. I am actually a malware fighter on my job. Thanks for the effort (+1) anyway. I'm afraid it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: When all else fails try another sound card of the same make, model and firmware, if the problem resolves itself then you have some proof the hardware is faulty, otherwise it is some sort of compatibility issue or possibly a bad motherboard or pci slot.

Comment: pretty hard to to for a laptop model. But I'll see what I can do there.

Comment: HP Elitebook 8740w as stated in my question.

Comment: Blind today, sorry, you can try this diagnostic software from HP, it is for a server but I found it works on many HP products, it has extensive hardware testing functions, Insight Diagnostics is the software on the Bootable CD you will boot from...http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=US&swItem=MTX-d69c8dfaf9c04dd2833bca45ca&mode=5

Comment: Accepting although the problem is not solved. I will purchase a support option from HP and have them repair it.